# ¿Como puedo conectar laravel con oracle?

Tags: base-de-datos, laravel-5, oracle, oracle-11g, composer

Probé tutoriales, tales como este:https://laraveles.com/utilizando-laravel-con-oracle/ y la verdad no me sirve, ni siquiera me deja instalar el 
`composer require yajra/aravel-oci8:"5.1.*"`
Mi laravel es version `5.8`
La version de mi oracle es `11g`
Version de composer `1.8.5`

Comment: que errores te da al intentar instalar el  `composer require yajra/aravel-oci8:"5.1.*"`?

Comment: Problem 1
    - Conclusion: remove laravel/framework v5.8.16
    - Conclusion: don't install laravel/framework v5.8.16
    - yajra/laravel-oci8 5.1.x-dev requires illuminate/database ~5.1.20 -> satisfiable by illuminate/database[5.1.x-dev, v5.1.20, v5.1.22, v5.1.25, v5.1.28, v5.1.30, v5.1.31, v5.1.41].

Comment: - yajra/laravel-oci8 v5.1.0 requires illuminate/database ~5.1.20 -> satisfiable by illuminate/database[5.1.x-dev, v5.1.20, v5.1.22, v5.1.25, v5.1.28, v5.1.30, v5.1.31, v5.1.41].
    - yajra/laravel-oci8 v5.1.1 requires illuminate/database ~5.1.20 -> satisfiable by illuminate/database[5.1.x-dev, v5.1.20, v5.1.22, v5.1.25, v5.1.28, v5.1.30, v5.1.31, v5.1.41].
    - yajra/laravel-oci8 v5.1.2 requires illuminate/database ~5.1.20 -> satisfiable by illuminate/database[5.1.x-dev, v5.1.20, v5.1.22, v5.1.25, v5.1.28, v5.1.30, v5.1.31, v5.1.41].

Comment: - yajra/laravel-oci8 v5.1.3 requires illuminate/database ~5.1.20 -> satisfiable by illuminate/database[5.1.x-dev, v5.1.20, v5.1.22, v5.1.25, v5.1.28, v5.1.30, v5.1.31, v5.1.41].
    - yajra/laravel-oci8 v5.1.4 requires illuminate/database ~5.1.20 -> satisfiable by illuminate/database[5.1.x-dev, v5.1.20, v5.1.22, v5.1.25, v5.1.28, v5.1.30, v5.1.31, v5.1.41].
    - don't install illuminate/database 5.1.x-dev|don't install laravel/framework v5.8.16

Comment: - don't install illuminate/database v5.1.20|don't install laravel/framework v5.8.16
    - don't install illuminate/database v5.1.22|don't install laravel/framework v5.8.16
    - don't install illuminate/database v5.1.25|don't install laravel/framework v5.8.16
    - don't install illuminate/database v5.1.28|don't install laravel/framework v5.8.16
    - don't install illuminate/database v5.1.30|don't install laravel/framework v5.8.16
    - don't install illuminate/database v5.1.31|don't install laravel/framework v5.8.16

Comment: - Installation request for laravel/framework (locked at v5.8.16, required as 5.8.*) -> satisfiable by laravel/framework[v5.8.16].
    - Installation request for yajra/laravel-oci8 5.1.* -> satisfiable by yajra/laravel-oci8[5.1.x-dev, v5.1.0, v5.1.1, v5.1.2, v5.1.3, v5.1.4].Installation failed, reverting ./composer.json to its original content

Comment: Por favor utiliza el botón [editar](https://es.stackoverflow.com/posts/270556/edit) y agrega todo a la pregunta principal y no como comentarios. Te invito ademas a realizar el [tour] para que conozcas el funcionamiento del sitio.

Comment: http://www.forosdelweb.com/f100/conectar-oracle-10g-con-php-703878/

Answer (score 1):

Estimado,
En mi caso yo resolví el problema con los siguientes pasos:

1. Descargar dll de oci8 desde "https://pecl.php.net/package/oci8/2.2.0/windows", se debe descargar según version de php y arquitectura x86 o x64.
2. copiar el archivo php_oci8.dll (como dato, mi version de PHP es la 7.4.2) y pegarlo en la ruta ..\xampp\php\ext (Dependiendo donde se encuentre instalado php).
3. Agregar la extension "extension=php_oci8.dll" al archivo php.ini.
4. Abrir la consola en el proyecto y utilizar nuevamente el comando "composer require yajra/laravel-oci8".

Con estos pasos logré instalar la libreria.

Saludos